# Как получить содержимое веб страницы средствами php, если большая часть этой страницы подгружается динамически?

Tags: php, html

Всем привет! Для получения содержимого веб страницы средствами php использую код

```
$delivery = file_get_contents('https://book24.ru/delivery/');
```

Но в итоге получаю только ту часть контента, которая загружается мгновенно, после выполнения функции не найти к примеру "Курьерская доставка". Подскажите пожалуйста, как получить всё как после полной загрузки страницы

Comment: https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver

Answer (score 1):

Если страница сайта который парсиш выводиться через js динамически, то  средствами php стандартными ты это не возьмешь, может и есть какие то модули самодельные для php но я не встречал,именно модули dll в которых реализован браузер. На python,java,с++ такие решения думаю что есть, ведь для того чтоб считать динамический контекст на сайте, тебе нужен по сути свой программный браузер, некий класс, который обратиться к сайту скачает с него все скрипты и построит всю dom модель, и потом ее разберет. php это не делает